# Throwing exception from member constructor (brace initializer vs initializer list)

Tags: c++

I have lost faith (and probably 2 hours) in my understanding of what happens when exception is thrown (from constructor) during initialization of member object.

Let me show you the example:

```
int init (int f) {
    throw f;
}

struct X {
    X (int f) : n {init (f)} {}
    int n;
};

struct P {
    X x {20};
};
```

and the usage:

```
int main (int argc, char** argv) {
    try {
        P p {};
    }
    catch (int n) {
        std::cout << n << "\n";
    }
}
```

This code (C++11 mode) compiles fine (using GCC 7.2.1) and under the Linux (Centos 7.4.1708) I get:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'int'
[1]    1242 abort (core dumped)  ./main
```

Question is: **Why?**
**Why `catch()` section was not taken?**

I have tracked the issue, meaning that when my `P` class looks a little bit different:

```
struct P {
    P (int f) : x {f} {}
    X x;
};
```

and with initialization of `p` object in this form: `P p {20}` result is: 20, which was expected, **no core dump**.

Could someone explain me what is the difference between initializing a member using *brace-or-equal-initializer* and *member-initializer-list* in the context of exceptions?

Bug report: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=85363

Comment: Interestingly enough, compiling your code with `-std=c++11` yields the result you mentioned, but everything looks good with `c++14` or `c++17`.

Comment: Seems like a compiler bug to me. Considering what JBL found out, and that the code works fine in clang++ in c++11 mode. And that I don't think there's anything wrong with the program

Comment: Yup, works on [coliru with clang and c++11](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1b2cb1b3fbd5acdc)

Comment: I can reproduce this with VS2015. Adding `P() {}` allows the exception to be caught but `P() = default;` doesn't help. `std::is_nothrow_default_constructible<P>::value;` seems to be `true` which is a problem. It seems that the default member intializers aren't taken into account when deciding the default constructor's `noexcept`ness.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux That's strange. `std::is_nothrow_default_constructible<P>::value;` is [false in g++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cd6d83110b0e9c09) even when it does fail to catch.

Comment: I can reproduce with `g++ -std=c++11`, but unable to reproduce with Visual C++ 2017 (for any value of `/std:`). Please report the bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no practical difference between:

```
struct P {
    X x {20};
};
```

and

```
struct P {
    P() : x{20} { }
    X x;
};
```

But there's a [GCC bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=85363) for C++11 mode (but not C++14 or later) which causes the initialization of `p{}` to happen outside the try-block, or adds the equivalent of `noexcept` to the implicitly-defined default constructor for 
`P`.

Comment: Since OP reported the bug I thought it was already linked to in the comments, but apparently not.